# Matching a regex expression and storing it

Tags: regex, ksh

I want to search within a string for a regex expression, I am doing this as follows:

Suppose target="string with 1234 in"

```
if [[ "$target" =~ "{4}\d" ]] then
    val=...
fi
```

I want to capture the regex found i.e. I want val=1234. what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only looking for the 4-digit number, you'd use `/\b\d{4}\b/`

If you're wanting to capture the `val=` part as well, simply prefix that, so you'd have `/\bval=\d{4}\b/`

And lastly, if you have a case where you don't know what the `val` of the `val=` part is, replace `val` with `\w+`, then you'd have `/\b\w+=\d{4}\b/`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean sth. like `val = s/\D(\d\d\d\d)\D/$1/` , or `val = /\d{4}/` ?

Comment: This would return true on any 4 digit number yes, and 5 digit numbers... and 6... and 7... albeit it'd capture the first 4 digits of those numbers, but still probably not what he would want.

Comment: oh yeah, you are rigth, i fixed the first one

Answer (score 0):

The matched parts are held in the `.sh.match` array in ksh:

```
if [[ $target == *{4}(\d)* ]]; then
    val=${.sh.match[1]}
    # do something with $val
fi
```

Demo:

```
$ target="string with 1234 in"
$ [[ $target == *{4}(\d)* ]] && echo "${.sh.match[1]}"
1234
```